# How can I find which Homebrew package a certain file/binary belongs to (if any)?

Tags: homebrew, package-management

I often find myself forgetting what I installed to get a certain command.  On my Arch machine, I can simply run `pacman -Qo $(which <command>)` and it finds the associated package.

Does anyone know of a way to do this using `brew`?